# Centering inline-block element between floats

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have a header which contains elements on the left, middle, and right.  To achieve this, I have a float left div, a float right div, and a margin 0 auto div, as exampled here: http://jsfiddle.net/huggz/uuq4Z/1/

```
<div style="text-align: center;" >

    <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; float: right;"></div>

    <div style="background: green; margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;">
        <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px; background: orange;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have the middle div set inline-block in an attempt to allow the middle content to vary in width.  However doing so, makes the margin: auto treat the floated elements like they're actually holding space.  If left is wider than right, I end up with a slightly (or not so slightly) off-centered middle element.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, preferably without resorting to scripts.  If that need be the case, I'd rather just deal with the consequences of making middle column fixed width.

[EDIT]
I should mention, there are instances where no middle or right content will exist.

Answer (score 1):

you can use position instead of float: http://jsfiddle.net/uuq4Z/5/

```
<div style="text-align: center; position: relative;" >

    <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0"></div>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: blue; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;"></div>
    <div style="background: green; display: inline-block;">
        <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px; background: orange;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The only problem that prevents it from being a workable solution is that there are instances where there isn't any middle content.  I'll edit that little nugget of info into the OP.  The solution, which isn't a horrible one, is to set the height of the elements with a script, but I'd rather not have to.

Comment: another solution would be to use a table with table-layout fixed:
http://jsfiddle.net/uuq4Z/7/ but there it is difficult to get a centered layout.. actually i dont really get the point what you intend to do :D

and in addition: this would work even if the middle or right element does not exist, since they are positioned independend of each other. except you want to have a different layout (e.g. the middle element at the right side if the right does not exist?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 100px; 
                background: red; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; 
                background: blue; float: right;"></div>

    <div style="background: green; display: block; margin: 0 100px 0 200px;">
        <div style="width: 150px; height: 100px; 
                    background: orange; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

with the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AFQV3/

I would keep the center element in-flow (not floated) and set the left and right
margins so allow for the left and right floated elements.

The center div will then have a block of space in which you can set other elements,
for example, the orange div, which you center between the floats.